# Generate charts with asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, charts

I'm doing a project with MVC in asp.net and C#.
I have to display the chart of yearly orders.The orders will be stored in MySqlServer db.
Please suggest me any idea how to do this.

Another requirement is I have to find the distance b/w 2 selected cities. Can I do this in my program??

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2):

If you want more Interactive `Charts` use [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/) to generate more Interactive Charts in your page

As @sebbzzz mentioned To calculate the distance between cities use [Google Map API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distancematrix/)

**Eg of Highcharts**

[3D Pie Chart](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/3d-pie) 
[image: 3D Pie Chart]

[Column Chart](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-basic)
[image: Column Chart]

Answer (score 1):

Probably what you are looking for is [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31397/New-Microsoft-Chart-Controls-for-Web-and-Windows-F).

This article is about Microsoft's own chart controls. One big plus point is they can be used as other controls like `TextBox` or `DropDownList` or a `Repeater`.

Meaning, you can do the coding server side and you can also have `aspx` markup.

Here's some sample aspx markup :

```
<asp:Chart ID="ChartSalesA" runat="server" Width="350px" Height="250px" 
    OnClick="Chart_Click" AutoPostBack="true"
    ToolTip="Previous 5 Weeks" BorderlineColor="Transparent"> 
    <Titles>
        <asp:Title Font="Calibri, 11pt, style=Bold" Name="Title1" Text="Previous 5 Weeks">
        </asp:Title>
    </Titles>
    <Legends>
        <asp:Legend Name="Default" Alignment="Center" BackColor="Lavender" BorderColor="Black" Docking="Bottom" LegendStyle="Row"> 
        </asp:Legend> 
    </Legends>
    <Series> 
        <asp:Series ChartType="Column" ChartArea="MainChartArea" Name="Series1" Color="#9955ff" Legend="Default" LegendText="Sales" XAxisType="Primary" XValueMember="yourValueORID" PostBackValue="#VALX"></asp:Series>
        <asp:Series ChartType="Line" ChartArea="MainChartArea" Name="Series2" YAxisType="Secondary" Legend="Default" Color="#99ccff" Enabled="True" LegendText="Customers" LabelBorderWidth="1" BorderWidth="3"></asp:Series>  
    </Series> 
    <ChartAreas> 
        <asp:ChartArea Name="MainChartArea" Area3DStyle-Enable3D="false">
            <AxisY Title="Weekly Sales"><LabelStyle Font="Calibri, 8pt" /></AxisY>
            <AxisY2 Title="Weekly Customers" ><LabelStyle Font="Calibri, 8pt" /></AxisY2>
            <AxisX Interval="1" IntervalType ="Weeks" IntervalAutoMode = "FixedCount"  ><LabelStyle Font="Calibri, 8pt" /></AxisX>
        </asp:ChartArea>
    </ChartAreas> 
</asp:Chart>
```

`yourValueORID` would be any column from the datasource you are binding to the chart.

You can handle the `Click` events on server side as below:

```
protected void Chart_Click(object sender, ImageMapEventArgs e) 
{
    //You will get your value from the XValueMember as below.
    string x = Convert.ToString(e.PostBackValue);
}
```

You can also do the same with `YValueMember="yourValueORID" PostBackValue="#VALY"`, if you want to pass your YValueMember to the code behind.

Answer (score 0):

[ChartJS](http://www.chartjs.org/) is a quite easy and customizable tool to generate graphs with. Just supply the data via Json from your controller. There's a lot of examples on how to do this in their site.

To calculate the distance between cities I'd suggest using [Google's Map API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distancematrix/)

Answer (score 0):

One other powerful charting library is [Shield UI's](http://demos.shieldui.com/aspnet/all-charts) - they also have ASP.NET wrapper components for the different chart functionalities.